# roslaunch can't find launch files with "catkin build"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I use "catkin_make" to build my workspace, and re-source my bashrc, then roslaunch is able to find my launch files and the nodes launch just fine.

If I do a "cakin clean -a" and a "cakin build," and re-source my bashrc, roslaunch can't autocomplete my launch files, or run any of the nodes in my workspace.

Here are the ROS related lines from my .bashrc:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo
export PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/bin:$PATH
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/ros/indigo/lib
```

The difference in my environment is only in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable:

with catkin tools ("catkin make"):

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/home/awagner/catkin_ws/src/image_retriever:/home/awagner/catkin_ws/src/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.4:/home/awagner/catkin_ws/src/bear_detector:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

with catkin_make:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/awagner/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

so catkin tools is appending ROS_PACKAGE_PATH with all of the subdirectories of my packages, rather than just the parent package.  Is this just a bug in the newer "python-catkin-tools" catkin front-end?  Anyone else running into this?

```
$ rospack profile 
Full tree crawl took
0.018942 seconds. Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may want to delete these directories. To get just of list of directories without manifests, re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.015500   /opt/ros/indigo/share
0.001762   /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share
0.000158 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libautocalib
0.000139 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libplanview
0.000066 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/bearvis
0.000042 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libautocalib/data
0.000027 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libdmd
0.000026 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libpdetect
0.000025 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc
0.000023 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libplanview/data
0.000023 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libbeardetect
0.000023 * /home/awagner/catkin_ws/install/share/libdepthio
0.000005 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
```

My version of catkin tools:
$ apt-cache show python-catkin-tools
Package: python-catkin-tools
Version: 0.3.0-1

I am running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214923/roslaunch-can%27t-find-launch-files-with-%22catkin-build%22/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-07-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that you have the catkin `install` option enabled for your workspace and you do not have install rules for the launch files in the packages CMakeLists.txt.

When install is enabled, `source devel/setup.bash` will source the `install` space instead of the `devel` one. To disable the install option do

```
catkin config --no-install
catkin clean --all
```

Then rebuild your workspace.

To add an install rule in your CMakeLists.txt, add:

```
install(DIRECTORY
launch
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [afakih](https://answers.ros.org/users/24990/afakih/) with karma: 206 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Here are the ROS related lines from my .bashrc:

> ```
> export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
> ```

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo
export PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/bin:$PATH
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/ros/indigo/lib
```

Apart from the `ROS_HOSTNAME` perhaps, all of this should not be necessary (unless you have a rather non-standard setup going on). Could you clarify why you think these should be in your `.bashrc`?

Sourcing `/path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` should setup all the required environment variables to work with packages build in that particular `catkin_ws`.

If you want, you could add `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc`, but the effect should be the same.

> If I do a "cakin clean -a" and a "cakin build," and re-source my bashrc, roslaunch can't autocomplete my launch files, or run any of the nodes in my workspace.

Which makes sense, because without sourcing the `setup.bash` from the workspace you are working with, none of the paths will be setup correctly.

Could you test by starting up a clean terminal, `unset` all the ROS related environment variables, sourcing the correct `setup.bash`, running `rospack profile` and then try `roslaunch`-ing one of your packages?

---

Edit:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
> ```

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

This is also not necessary: you only need to source the 'last' workspace. In this case, that would be `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-07-30**:
I actually had sourced the setup.bash; I just missed it when scraping the ROS crap out of my .bashrc  into this bug report.  Sorry about that.  I'm not sure why I'm having to force some of those ros environment variables; still tracking down why I need them.

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-07-30**:
I removed as many ros variables as I could.  (ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME were needed or roscore hangs on my machine).  I rebuilt, re- "rospack profile", started new shell.  No change in behavior.  Does "catkin make" play well with roslaunch on your machine?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-30**:
Yes, it should not matter whether you use `catkin_make` or `catkin build`. Both should result in a working `devel` or `install` space. A hanging `roscore` would suggest issues with DNS resolution, but that is outside the scope of the current issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-30**:
Could you remove everything (ROS) from your `.bashrc` (except `HOSTNAME` and `MASTER_URI`), save, start a new terminal, verify no `ROS_*` variables are set (nor extra entries added to `(LD_LIBRARY_)PATH` etc). *Then* source your devel space, try `rospack find image_retriever` (or something).

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-07-31**:
Hello, thanks for trying to help me with this.  There are a bunch of ROS variables set ~outside by my .bashrc (I inherited this laptop from a previous dev), and not in any of the usual places.  I will try to track that down first.  And I'll just use catkin_build in the mean-time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-31**:
Biggest problems are mostly caused by the various `PATH` variables. I'd try to remove all of those first, then work with a 'clean' terminal, only source a single `devel/setup.bash` and see what works and what doesn't. Then continue from there.